# Zabbix Agent Wont Discover Services with Remote Script

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I'm trying to create  template that relies on PowerShell scripts which enumerates the services on a remote Window server. It should then create an item for each service that defaults to disabled where I can go and enable the items that I want monitored. I have the below scripts, config changes, and template deployed, however no items ever populate.

```
################################################################################
# get_services.ps1
#
################################################################################

$services = Get-Service | select name

Write-Host "{"
Write-Host " `"data`":[`n"
ForEach($s in $services) {
    $line= "{ `"{#SERVICE}`" : `"" + $s.Name + "`" }"
    Write-Host $line
}
Write-Host
Write-Host " ]"
Write-Host "}"
```

---

```
################################################################################
# get_servicestate.ps1
#
################################################################################

Param ([String] $name = 0)
$service = Get-Service -Name $name
Write-Host $service.Status
```

---

```
### Option: UserParameter
#   User-defined parameter to monitor. There can be several user-defined parameters.
#   Format: UserParameter=<key>,<shell command>
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# UserParameter=
UserParameter=org.service.discovery,powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "S:\Zabbix\templates\Zabbix_Services_monitoring\get_services.ps1"
UserParameter=org.service.state[*],powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File S:\Zabbix\templates\Zabbix_Services_monitoring\get_servicestate.ps1 "$1"
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zabbix_export>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <date>2017-11-20T16:44:57Z</date>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <name>
                    Templates
                </name>
        </group>
    </groups>
    <templates>
        <template>
            <template>Template Microsoft Services</template>
            <name>Template Microsoft Services</name>
            <description/>
            <groups>
                <group>
                    <name>
                    Templates
                </name>
                </group>
            </groups>
            <applications>
                <application>
                    <name>Windows Services</name>
                </application>
            </applications>
            <items/>
            <discovery_rules>
                <discovery_rule>
                    <name>Windows Service</name>
                    <type>0</type>
                    <snmp_community/>
                    <snmp_oid/>
                    <key>org.service.discovery</key>
                    <delay>30</delay>
                    <status>1</status>
                    <allowed_hosts/>
                    <snmpv3_contextname/>
                    <snmpv3_securityname/>
                    <snmpv3_securitylevel>0</snmpv3_securitylevel>
                    <snmpv3_authprotocol>0</snmpv3_authprotocol>
                    <snmpv3_authpassphrase/>
                    <snmpv3_privprotocol>0</snmpv3_privprotocol>
                    <snmpv3_privpassphrase/>
                    <delay_flex/>
                    <params/>
                    <ipmi_sensor/>
                    <authtype>0</authtype>
                    <username/>
                    <password/>
                    <publickey/>
                    <privatekey/>
                    <port/>
                    <filter>
                        <evaltype>0</evaltype>
                        <formula/>
                        <conditions/>
                    </filter>
                    <lifetime>30</lifetime>
                    <description/>
                    <item_prototypes>
                        <item_prototype>
                            <name>Windows Service {#SERVICE}</name>
                            <type>0</type>
                            <snmp_community/>
                            <multiplier>0</multiplier>
                            <snmp_oid/>
                            <key>org.service.state[{#SERVICE}]</key>
                            <delay>30</delay>
                            <history>90</history>
                            <trends>0</trends>
                            <status>0</status>
                            <value_type>4</value_type>
                            <allowed_hosts/>
                            <units/>
                            <delta>0</delta>
                            <snmpv3_contextname/>
                            <snmpv3_securityname/>
                            <snmpv3_securitylevel>0</snmpv3_securitylevel>
                            <snmpv3_authprotocol>0</snmpv3_authprotocol>
                            <snmpv3_authpassphrase/>
                            <snmpv3_privprotocol>0</snmpv3_privprotocol>
                            <snmpv3_privpassphrase/>
                            <formula>1</formula>
                            <delay_flex/>
                            <params/>
                            <ipmi_sensor/>
                            <data_type>0</data_type>
                            <authtype>0</authtype>
                            <username/>
                            <password/>
                            <publickey/>
                            <privatekey/>
                            <port/>
                            <description/>
                            <inventory_link>0</inventory_link>
                            <applications>
                                <application>
                                    <name>Windows Services</name>
                                </application>
                            </applications>
                            <valuemap/>
                            <logtimefmt/>
                            <application_prototypes/>
                        </item_prototype>
                    </item_prototypes>
                    <trigger_prototypes>
                        <trigger_prototype>
                            <expression>{Template Microsoft Services:org.service.state[{#SERVICE}].str(Stopped)}&lt;&gt;0</expression>
                            <name>Windows Service {#SERVICE} is down</name>
                            <url/>
                            <status>0</status>
                            <priority>4</priority>
                            <description/>
                            <type>0</type>
                            <dependencies/>
                        </trigger_prototype>
                    </trigger_prototypes>
                    <graph_prototypes/>
                    <host_prototypes/>
                </discovery_rule>
            </discovery_rules>
            <macros/>
            <templates/>
            <screens/>
        </template>
    </templates>
</zabbix_export>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_services.ps1 does not generate valid JSON. Dictionary values need to be sepearted by a comma with the exception of the last item in the array. The corrected .ps1 file is below:

```
################################################################################
# get_services.ps1
#
################################################################################

$services = Get-Service | select name
$idx = 1

Write-Host "{"
Write-Host " `"data`":[`n"
ForEach($s in $services) {

    if ($idx -lt $services.count)
    {
        $line= "{ `"{#SERVICE}`" : `"" + $s.Name + "`" },"
        write-host $line
    }
    elseif ($idx -ge $services.count)
    {
        $line= "{ `"{#SERVICE}`" : `"" + $s.Name + "`" }"
        write-host $line
    }

    $idx++;

}
Write-Host
Write-Host " ]"
Write-Host "}"
```

Comment: Even with the valid JSON the services do not enumerate.

Comment: The template was disabled in addition to the JSON issue. It is now working.